# Freeing and deleting duplicates from a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, valgrind

My function remove_duplicates should get rid of the duplicate data values in a linked list. However, when it reaches a point in a linked list, for example if the linked list is `L = {10,10,20,30,30,30,40,50}`the output is `L = {10,20,30,(some random int value like 23687328),50}` when it should be `L = {10,20,30,40,50}`. Also, I'm checking the leakage and Valgrind tells me I am leaking somewhere, but I cannot find it.

```
typedef struct node_t
{
    int data;
    struct node_t *next;
} node;



void remove_duplicates(node * head)
{
    node* temp;
    while (head != NULL && head->next != NULL)
    {
        while (head->data == head->next->data)
        {
            temp = head->next->next;
            free(head->next);
            head->next = temp;
        }
        head = head->next;
    }
    free(temp);
}
```

I am using valgrind --leak-check=yes ./llistprac and the output is

```
==24802== 80 (16 direct, 64 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 5
==24802==    at 0x4A069EE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==24802==    by 0x400575: append (in /home/llistprac)
==24802==    by 0x4006D9: main (in /home/llistprac)
==24802== 
==24802== LEAK SUMMARY:
==24802==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==24802==    indirectly lost: 64 bytes in 4 blocks
==24802== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

Comment: Interestingly enough (at least to me) , when I dont free temp at the end, it works! But then I am still leaking...

Comment: When you say Valgrind tells you you're leaking but you can't find it, what arguments are you using and what is the Valgrind output?

Comment: You shouldn't need to free temp.

Comment: You shouldn't free temp! Chances are, you forgot a free elsewhere - most likely in another node delete or at list destruction

Comment: Why is this question being asked multiple times? @Bourezg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void remove_duplicates(node * head)
{
    node* temp;
    while (head != NULL && head->next != NULL)
    {
        if (head->data == head->next->data)
        {
            temp = head->next;
            head->next = head->next->next;
            free(temp);
        }
        else
            head = head->next;
    }
}
```

Every time you delete a node or move head to next node, you should always check if head-next is NULL.